# What is the alternative to the Observer Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

In [this](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/OrganizingPresentations.html#observer-gotchas) article, Martin Fowler recommends to use the observer pattern only between layer boundaries and to avoid to use it for dependencies in one layer. But what is the alternative to the observer pattern, if I still need some amount of decoupling?

Comment: Decoupling is usually needed because of the layers pattern (e.g., domain layer should not know details of the presentation layer, which tends to evolve a lot and would therefore make the domain layer unstable). Do you have a concrete example of two objects in the same layer that need decoupling but also need synchronizing? I don't think you can get a great answer without more details.

Comment: Please provide the case you need observer pattern inside a layer.

Comment: Have a look at the [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).